# Select operator based on stream value

Tags: rxjs

There is one data source that emits values 0 or 1.

If 0 I want to pipe it throught switchMap operator.

If 1 I want to pipe it throught exhaustMap operator.

How can I do that?

https://stackblitz.com/edit/rxjs-gcvsfe

```
const source = from([0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1]).pipe(
  // if value === 0
  switchMap(value => {
    return of("Operator switchMap, value: " + value);
  })
  // if value === 1
  // exhaustMap(value => {
  //   return of('Operator exhaustMap, value: ' + value)
  // })
);

source.subscribe(console.log);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to switch operators, then you probably want to have 2 different streams.

If this is the case, then you can use the `filter` operator and have something like this

```
const source = from([0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1]);

const stream_0 = source.pipe(
  filter(val => val === 0),
  switchMap(value => {
    return of("Operator switchMap, value: " + value);
  })
)
const stream_1 = source.pipe(
  filter(val => val === 1),
  exhaustMap(value => {
     return of('Operator exhaustMap, value: ' + value)
  })
);

merge(stream_0, stream_1).subscribe(console.log);
```

Answer (score 0):

I end up with this (exhaustMap is inside custom operator paginateList)

```
this._baseSubject = new Subject<ListPaged>();
this._nextPageSubject = new Subject<ListPaged>();

this._items$ = this._baseSubject.pipe(
  switchMap((req) => {
    return this._nextPageSubject.pipe(
      startWith(req),
      paginateList(paginate)
    );
  })
);
```